# Best way to dynamically add rows to TableLayout in Android

Tags: android, header, rows, tablelayout

I am new to developing in Android, so below are some really basic questions, but I feel like populating a table in Android is not straightforward.
I have a list of objects and would like to add each object to a row in my TableView.
Also I would like to have a fixed header with fixed columns.

Each header cell should have the same width as all the other row cells in that same column.

Question 1: How do I add a column? By adding multiple TextViews to a TableRow and foreseeing borders myself? Isn't that done automatically?

Question 2: If I add a new TableRow dynamically to the TableLayout and add the same amount of columns as the header (aka new TextViews?), will these automatically have the same width as the header's column?

Question 3: Is there an easy how-to that would anwser my questions? I've been googling for a while now and I don't seem to find any simple tutorial.

[image]

Comment: You should use a ListView or RecycleView instead. Examples all over the internet.

Comment: if your table rows are similar, then it's better to use `RecyclerView` instead of `TableLayout`

Answer (score -1):

You should use RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager